# web analytics without the help of google analytics

Tags: web-analytics

I am trying to display dashboards to every user who accesses my website with an analysis of his previous data. Can I do it without the help of google analytics?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. If you're looking for a recommendation, it's off-topic. If you're not, this is far to broad of a question.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you do not want to use `Google-Analytics` then YES you can do it.

Few steps you need to do:

- Create a database table in which save page URL and visitor's ip
- Also try to get time that how many seconds/minutes visitor stay on page
- You may generate reports and show on dashboard

By the way, if we have a free of cost solution then why you are spending time on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip is free and ethical: [Website](https://paperclip.live). Users can see all the data collected about them. I'm in their beta program, where you can suggest things to them and they'll add it.